# What are the masters funded opportunities for a British citizen living abroad?

Tags: masters, funding, international-students

Since I have been living in Pakistan for the past 6 years (completed my Bachelors of Electrical Engineering from here), I find myself not eligible for most academic scholarships in the UK.

1. For international students, the scholarship criteria usually states that I should not be a British Citizen
2. For British students, the scholarship criteria usually states that I should have been nominally residing in the UK to be eligible for the scholarship or even for standard UK/EU student fees

So I am at the worst of both ends! What do I do?

I am looking for an opportunity preferably in the UK but would be willing to go elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

As an EU citizen, you are eligible for free education in Sweden:

https://studyinsweden.se

Comment: And all the nordic countries, actually.